# xml serialization of empty string as nil

Tags: c#, xml, serialization

In C# is it possible to serialize empty string as nil value.
Let's take the object like this:

```
var myBook = new Book(){ Author = "John S.", ISBN = null };
```

I'd like to have:

```
<Book>
  <Author>John S.</Author>
  <ISBN nil="true"/>
</Book>
```

Is it possible to achieve such a result with one of third party xml serializers like ExtendedXmlSerializer or YAXLib?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this :

```
var myBook = new Book() { Author = "John S.", ISBN = null };
XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Book));
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
xs.Serialize(sw, myBook);
Console.WriteLine(sw.ToString() );
```

Also you need to add an attribute :

```
public class Book
{
    public string Author { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(IsNullable = true)]
    public string ISBN { get; set; }
}
```

Result :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Book xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Author>John S.</Author>
  <ISBN xsi:nil="true" />
</Book>
```